# istio_response_bytes_sum and istio_request_bytes_sum show different value for a service ..why?

Tags: prometheus, istio, envoyproxy, istio-kiali, istio-prometheus

I am looking for the metrics emitted by istio , but I find it weird that value returned by the metric istio_response_bytes_sum is almost double the value returned by istio_request_bytes_sum
sum(rate(istio_response_bytes_sum{reporter="destination",destination_service_name="XXXXX"}[5m]))  -> value -> 91.290
sum(rate(istio_request_bytes_sum{reporter="destination",destination_service_name="XXXXX"}[5m])) -> value -> 41.54

Please help [![request][1]][1]

[![response][2]][2]

Values are double here .
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8fKW.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrrLc.png

Comment: Why do you think it's something out of ordinary? For example, if your service is heavily skewed to writing operations this kind of relation between received and responded bytes is normal.

Comment: Thanks @markalex , but this is my dev environment and the system is not under load , is this normal in that case ?

Comment: It's hard to definitively answer this without knowing what is going on in your system. But it is not out of ordinary to be worried about. Plus, I just noticed: values you showed contradict your statement: actually response value is two times more that request value. And it is very much usual situation.

Comment: Ah sorry  it is actually response. is double ,editing my statement . Is there any way I can drill down to see what gets added in reposne , via kiali or so ?